# How to prove this real analysis problem?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

[image: Prove]

I cannot seem to prove this because the supremum is A is positive infinity, this also goes for B.

Comment: Let's break it down a little.
  
Let us denote $M=\sup A$. We want to prove that $\sup B=M^2$.  
That means we need to prove two things:  

 1. $M^2$ is an upper bound: for each $b\in B$, $b\leq M^2$.
 2. $M^2$ is the lowest upper bound: if $K$ satisfies $\forall b\in B :\; b\leq K $ then $M^2\leq K$.

Can you prove these two, knowing that they hold for $M$ as the supremum of $A$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since $(\sup (A))^2 \geq a^2$ for all $a \in A$, we have $(\sup (A))^2 \geq \sup (B)$.

The converse is similar: since $\sup (B) \geq a^2$ means $\sqrt{\sup (B)} \geq a$ for all $a$ because $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is montonically increasing on its domain; so in turn it's greater than $\sup (A)^2$ and so on.